# Cassandra reads slow when add new node

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I'm using cassandra 3.11.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 (VM).
So with 2 nodes in same cluster using 0.8s for `select * from emp`.
But when i add new node in same cluster it using 2.0s

Keyspace

```
class: SimpleStrategy
replication_factor: 2
```

Table

```
CREATE TABLE emp (key int PRIMARY KEY,empname text);
```

Cassandra.yaml

Node1 and Node2 have a same config

```
autobootstrap: false
seed provider: "node1,node2"
num_tokens: 256
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
```

Node3 (new node) config

```
autobootstrap: true
seed provider: "node1,node2"
num_tokens: 256
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
```

Comment: is there anything in logs to suggest GCs are causing pauses?

Comment: Nothing happen during query. My read/write consistency is ONE. So i have a question if RF=3 with 3 nodes. How many node that cassandra retrieve data. In my suggest is 1 node because each node have a 100% of data.